# ¿Se puede hacer una lista enlazada dinámica?

Tags: java, lista

Quisiera saber si hay la manera de hacer una lista enlazada dinámica, por ejemplo pedir 4 dígitos y que el tamaño de esa lista solo me permita ingresar cuatro datos

```
    public class Nodo {


    int dato;
    Nodo siguiente;



}



    public class Lista_Simple {


    Nodo primero;
    Nodo ultimo;

    public Lista_Simple() {

        primero=null;
        ultimo=null;   
    }


    public void crear(int dato) {     
        Nodo nuevo_nodo = new Nodo();
        nuevo_nodo.dato = dato;

        if (primero == null) {

            primero=nuevo_nodo;
            primero.siguiente = nuevo_nodo;
            ultimo = primero;
        } else {
             nuevo_nodo.siguiente = null;
            ultimo.siguiente = nuevo_nodo;

            ultimo = nuevo_nodo;
        }

    }

    public void imprimir(){

        Nodo actual=new Nodo();
        actual=primero;

        while(actual!=null){

            System.out.println(actual.dato);
            actual=actual.siguiente;


        }


    }



}

    public class Principal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

         Lista_Simple ls=new Lista_Simple();
    ls.crear(15);
    ls.crear(4);
    ls.crear(44);


    ls.imprimir();
    }
```

Comment: La respuesta corta es "Sí". Sólo tienes que contar y guardar el número de elementos de la lista.

Comment: @PabloLozano como le doy el tamaño?? eso es lo que no entiendo

Comment: @PabloLozano disculpa como se imprimiria esa lista?

Comment: Te lo he añadido abajo

Answer (score 1):

La solución es tener un contador de elementos en tu lista:

```
public class ListaDinamica {

    public static class Nodo {
        int dato;
        Nodo siguiente;
    }
    Nodo primero;
    Nodo ultimo;
    int maxLong;
    int longitudActual=0;

    ListaDinamica(int longitud) {
        this.maxLong=longitud;
    }

    public void incluyeNodo(Nodo n) {
        if (longitudActual==0) {
            primero=n;
            ultimo=n;
        } else if (longitudActual<maxLong) {
            ultimo.siguiente=n;
            ultimo=n;
            longitudActual++;
        }

    }

    public String toString() {
        if (this.longitudActual==0) {
            return "[]";
        }
        StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder("[");
        Nodo aux=this.primero;
        while (aux != null) {
            sb.append(aux.dato);
            if (aux.siguiente!=null) {
                sb.append(",");
            }else {
                sb.append("]");
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }


}
```

De igual modo, puedes eliminar elementos, reduciendo la longitud